# Can I specify the object type at runtime?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, generics, reflection

If I have a generic application framework for a variety of business applications that use multiple different data sources for a multitude of scenarios, can all the objects be specified at runtime using reflection or declared as `object`, or is this bad practice?

For instance, I need to bind an arbitrary data source to a Winforms grid. Is it good practice to operate completely generically, evaluating the properties and fields at runtime as opposed to specifically declaring the types?

Scenario:

```
Private sub ugdJobs(sender as object, e as InitializeLayoutEventArgs) handles ugdJobs.InitializeLayout

sender.datasource = something

End sub
```

As opposed to

```
private sub ugdJobs(sender as object, e as InitializeLayoutEventArgs) handles ugdJobs.InitializeLayout

Dim jobdata as bindinglist(of DAL.jobs)(DAL.jobslist.getall()) 

Ugdjobs.datasource = jobdata
End Sub
```

What is the point of explicitly declaring the type of ugdjobs.datasource?

Answer (score 1):

The `DataSource` property that you're assigning to is almost certainly type `Object` anyway, so there's no advantage to knowing the specific type of the object assigned from the perspective of data binding. If you want to use that object elsewhere then there may be some advantage to knowing that specific type. If you were binding to a `ComboBox` or the like then you'd have to know something about the items in the list in order to set the `DisplayMember` and/or `ValueMember` properties but a grid that creates a column for every property/column in the data source will do it all for you.

Comment: Yes, and you can configure the Display Member/Value Member in the design editor without actually having to write any code.